# Plot data.tree coloring and labelling by level

Tags: r, plot, data.tree

I have the following data.tree structure.

```
d <- structure(list(SUBZONE = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A8", "B10",  "B11", "B2", "B3", "B4"), 
                    ZONE = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                    ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L)), 
               .Names = c("SUBZONE", "ZONE", "ID"), 
               row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
               class = "data.frame")

d$pathString <- paste("all", d$ZONE,d$SUBZONE, sep = "/")
alltree <-as.Node(d)
plot(alltree)
```

This tree has three different levels, according to the graph and `alltree$Get(function(x) c(level = x$level))`:

[image]

I want to achieve two things when formatting this plot:

1. Color by level the boxes,
2. Label by label.

[image]

I don't know how to access the levels even though I tried. In this case I have "named" nodes but it's not the case for all the trees I have so I want to acces them by its level number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of all the nodes in a level by using `Traverse`:

```
level1 <- Traverse(alltree, filterFun = function(x) x$level == 1)
level2 <- Traverse(alltree, filterFun = function(x) x$level == 2)
level3 <- Traverse(alltree, filterFun = function(x) x$level == 3)
```

This allows you to color the nodes as required like this:

```
Do(level1, SetNodeStyle, style = "filled", fillcolor = "#fff200", 
   fontcolor = "black", inherit = FALSE)
Do(level2, SetNodeStyle, style = "filled", fillcolor = "#feadc9", 
   fontcolor = "black", inherit = FALSE)
Do(level3, SetNodeStyle, style = "filled", fillcolor = "#b5e51a", 
   fontcolor = "black", inherit = FALSE)
```

Which gives this result:

```
plot(alltree)
```

[image]

In terms of plotting the levels, I cannot find any native way to do this within the package itself, though presumably if you export to `DiagrammeR` format this would be possible.